# Saving universal time in c# for a users local date time passed in to server hosted in azure

Tags: c#, azure, datetime, datetime-format

Maybe I don't understand the 'ToUniversalTime()' method in C#, but I want to take my users local time 'eventDateTime' and get the universal time to save in my table

I'm passing in a date time (ex. a date time for Pacific Standard Time PST) and I want to get the universal time, but my result is the same. Do I need to get the time zone offset in javascript and use that somehow first?

Here is how I'm testing and this is running in Azure

eventDateTime is passed in from the user here it's 12/21/2017 @ 5:15PM and 
t1 is the same as eventdatetime. T2,T3,T4 is 12/21/2017 @ 11:01:57PM

```
var t1 = eventDateTime.ToUniversalTime();
var t2 = DateTime.UtcNow;
var t3 = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
var t4 = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: Why not pass a UT?

Comment: what do you mean? do you mean convert the date time in javascript to a universal time and then pass that in and use that?

Comment: you should do your best to do DateTime work in UTC as soon as possible.

Comment: My date times will be coming in from all time zones. so I think its irrelavant what the server time zone is right?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of DateTime.ToUniversalTime is dependent on the DateTime's Kind property. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, the value returned by the ToUniversalTime method is determined by the Kind property of the current DateTime object. The following table describes the possible results.
>
> DateTimeKind.Utc: No conversion is performed.
>
> DateTimeKind.Local: The current DateTime object is converted to UTC.
>
> DateTimeKind.Unspecified: The current DateTime object is assumed to be a local time, and the conversion is performed as if Kind were Local.

What kind of DateTime are you receiving? If you're parsing a DateTime in a web service, was it transmitted in a format that preserves time zone information like [ISO 8601](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Newtonsoft, Newtonsoft will deserialize to your DateTime property as UTC. So you do not need to do anything on deserialization. If your DateTime is retrieved from SQL Server, its DateTimeKind will be Unspecified. You need to set it.

```
eventDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(eventDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

And then Newtonsoft will serialize it as UTC and your user's javascript client will have the time in your user's correct time zone.